# API for getting crawl status of various content sources?

Tags: search, crawling

Is there an API to determine if Sharepoint/MOSS/SearchServer is currently crawling a particular content source?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can determine the crawling status for SharePoint 2010:

```
SearchService searchService = SearchService.Service;
// replace "Search Service Application" with actual Search Service Application Name
SearchServiceApplication searchApp = 
          searchService.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>("Search Service Application"); 


Content content = new Content(searchApp);

foreach (ContentSource contentSource in content.ContentSources)
{
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", contentSource.Name, contentSource.CrawlStatus));
}
```

The content source crawl status is retrieved via [ContentSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.contentsource.aspx). It is available for both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2007. You can check [MSDN sample for SharePoint 2007 here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.contentsource%28office.12%29.aspx).

In 2010, it's even easier with PowerShell:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource
```